# How to add users to the same channel in agora flutter?

Tags: flutter, call, channel, agora.io

In the old version of agora rtc engine there were no token , but now there is token that will be generated for a channel name , How can I  connect users to the same channel while doing a video call with agora and flutter

Answer (score 0):

Agora uses token for authentication when your user joins an RTC channel. This token is a temporary string that needs to be generated again after every 24hrs. You can generate this token either from your Agora dashboard or to autogenerate this token after every 24hrs you can refer to this guide which explains the complete process: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server?platform=All%20Platforms

You can pass this token value in the `joinChannel()` method along with the channel name. This way your user can join a channel.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure uniqueness in channel names, it is recommended to use a distinct identifier that is unique to each chat. In this case, the chat ID can be used as the channel name, which ensures that all users in the same chat will be assigned to the same channel. This approach can help avoid naming conflicts and streamline communication within the chat platform.

```
_client = AgoraClient(
      agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
        appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        channelName: widget.chateId, //here
      ),
    );
```